# Parse HTTP Request Arduino

Tags: arduino-ide, esp8266, string, http

I am sending a HTTP Request to my WiFi module `http://192.168.4.1/STA/ID=HelloWorld/Pass=Testin123`

How can I parse above string in Arduino. First I need to check for `STA`, if it exists, continue to scan the string. Put Value of `ID`, in this case `HelloWorld` should be store in String data type `SSID` and Value of `Pass`, in this case `Testin123` should be store in String data type `Pass`.

How can achieve above using ARDUINO code! Please help.

Comment: Are you sure you don't need to parse `GET /STA/ID=HelloWorld/Pass=Testin123 HTTP/1.1`, as that is what's send in the http request?

Comment: I would use `strtok()` using `/` as the token separator.

Comment: @Gerben Exactly that is!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your incoming string, as Gerben has mentioned, will actually be more like:

```
GET /STA/ID=HelloWorld/Pass=Testin123 HTTP/1.1
```

My personal preferred method is to use `strtok()` to split the string up.  I'd use a two-pass method for this.

First split the string up into three parts - one GET, one the request, and the third the request type (though you don't need to use that for anything).  Assume the string is in C string `incoming`:

```
char *get = strtok(incoming, " ");
char *request = strtok(NULL, " ");
char *rtype = strtok(NULL, " ");
```

The request is now pointed to by the `*request` pointer and the string has been sliced up in-place.  So now you can do something similar with the request, this time splitting on `/` instead of space:

```
String SSID;
String Pass;

if (request != NULL) {
    char *part = strtok(request, "/");

    bool seenSTA = false;
    while (part) { // While there is a section to process...

        if (seenSTA) {
            if (!strncmp(part, "ID=", 3)) { // We have the ID
                SSID = String(part + 3);
            } else if (!strncmp(part, "Pass=", 5)) { // We have the password
                Pass = String(part + 5);
            }
        } else if (!strcmp(part, "STA")) { 
            seenSTA = true;
        }

        part = strtok(NULL, "/");
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought `Strings` are evil :D

Comment: @TisteAndii they are, which is why I do it all as C strings and then finally convert it to String which Anuj wants (supposedly).

Comment: @Majenko What about `STA` part? How to check that?

Comment: The same way as the others, but you don't need to specify the length since it's the entire string you are looking for. `if (!strcmp(part, "STA")) { ... whatever here ... }`

Comment: @Majenko I tried this but It can't find `STA` in entire link. Always showing `Not found`. Here is [ArduinoCode](https://ideone.com/1IKy6w)

Comment: You can't nest like that. You get exactly ONE part of the string each pass through the `while`. If you want to only look for specific things if you have seen `STA` then you have to remember the fact that you have seen `STA` in an earlier pass.

Comment: @Majenko What actually I need to do is, confirm the presence of `STA` in string. If it is not present, do not enter into loop. If it exits, search for `ID` and `Pass`. It should only be single loop process. No need of while loop. Also using `while()` loop in arduino `void loop()` is not preferred, it crashes the program.

Comment: There is absolutely nothing wrong with using `while` on any platform. If it takes longer than the watchdog timeout then kick the dog. I have told you what you need to do. What part of it don't you understand?

Comment: I have enhanced my example to show you explicitly how to implement it.

Comment: @Majenko It worked well. Sorry for bothering you everywhere! I was really confused. It works well now. I understand the whole thing as well.